# How to specify gender e multiple cip code facebook

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I want to specify in the query gender and multiple zip:

```
act_xxxxx/reachestimate?currency=EUR&optimize_for=OFFSITE_CONVERSIONS&targeting_spec={ "geo_locations":{"zips":[{"key":"IT:89040"},{"key":"IT:87100"}]},"age_min": 20,"age_max": 40}
```

Another problem is that If I execute query I obtain this is the  result:

```
{
  "data": {
    "users": 22000,
    "estimate_ready": true
  }
}
```

This result is the sum again the users of first zip code and the users of second zip code but I I do not want this, I want to read (in the result)  the users of first zip code  and the users of second zip code separately. Can Anyone help me?

Comment: If you want them separate, then you should make two requests, for two separate reach estimates.

Comment: @CBroe is there no way to make a single call and have the two answers?

Comment: @CBroe 'genders':[1] is the query is male or female?